# How to create a Callback function by Using C/C++

Tags: c++, callback

does C\C++ Support a mechanism for callback function ? and how to create it ?
I've written several code, to create callback function in C++ but it failed ..

```
    #include<iostream>
    using namespace std;

    void callee()
    {
         printf("callee\n"); 
         printf("calleeeeeeeeee\n"); 
    }

    void callback(void* func)
    {
         printf("callback\n");     
    }

    int main()
    {
        void (*call)(void*);
        void (*call2)(void);
        call2 = &callee;
        call = &callback;
        call((void*)call2);    
        getchar();
        return 0;    
    }
```

Comment: Note: This isn't C code. What is your error message?

Comment: `call((void*)call2);` is most likely your error cause...simply because a function pointer cannot be cast to a void *. Each function parameter needs to match the function prototype. So no, generic callbacks are not supported if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: There was no error but it only gave me "callback" as an output, the "callee" function didn't executed :(

Comment: For the general part of the question, see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2298242/callback-functions-in-c

Comment: This SO question may help you on your way. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2485219/generic-callbacks

Comment: have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6183847/callback-functions-in-c-c-c   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2298242/callback-functions-in-c  http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/cpp/cpp_mfc/callbacks/article.php/c10557/Callback-Functions-Tutorial.htm, these link should help you understand basic concept behind callback and their usage...

Comment: Um... `iostream` and `namespace std` are not `c`. Please use tags that actually apply to your question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't know C++, I wrote up some C code, hope it helps

```
#include <stdio.h>

void call( int, void ( *f )( int ) );
void called( int );

int main( int argc, char const *argv[] ){
    printf( "start\n" );
    call( 1, called );
    printf( "end\n" );
    getchar();
    return 0;
}

void call( int a, void ( *f )( int ) ){
    printf( "doing stuff\n" );
    printf( "a: %d\n", a );
    printf( "going to call back\n" );
    f( a * 2 );
}

void called( int b ){
    printf( "b: %d\n", b );
    printf( "b*2: %d\n", b*2 );
    printf( "call back function being called\n" );
}
```

Calling call back functions in a function is no more than having a function pointer and call the function whenever you finished your planed job.

I modified the code and made it up to be more clear to show how you would use call backs.
This is the result you will see, if you compile and run it:

```
start
doing stuff
a: 1
going to call back
b: 2
b*2: 4
call back function being called
end
```

*Well, either the author edited the question or someone edited it for him, there's no longer the C tag. Ignore this answer if you don't want to see pure C code. I'm just gonna leave it here in case anyone could be interested.*

Comment: Nice :), i got that :) Thank you :)

Comment: @prM, +1. What do you mean by "whenever you finished your planed job"? Thanks!

Comment: @user1847726 err, just a function call (to the given function pointer) statement at the very end of the function body.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you never called "callee" - you executed "callback" with "call(void*)call2);", but in order for your "callee" function to execute, you need to run it from within your 
"callback" function.
Here, this works:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;

void callee()
{
     printf("callee\n");
     printf("calleeeeeeeeee\n");
}

void callback(void* func)
{
    void (*mCallbackFunc)(void);

    printf("callback\n");

    mCallbackFunc = (void(*)())func;
    mCallbackFunc();
}

int main()
{
    void (*call)(void*);
    void (*call2)(void);
    call2 = &callee;
    call = &callback;

    call((void*)call2);

    return 0;
}
```

**Output:**

```
callback
callee
calleeeeeeeeee
```

Comment: hmm ouh i have to execute the function that is passed into parameter, right ?

Comment: Bingo! That's exactly it. Operations with function pointers are often easier to read if you typedef the function pointer first, but it's just a matter of looking pretty. As you point out - you need to explicitly do something with  the passed in parameter - in this case, execute the function it points to.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of using callbacks with interfaces.

```
//listener observer design pattern
class MonitoringElements{
public:

//information to monitor

};

class ICondition{
public:
    virtual ~ICondition(){}

    virtual bool didTrigger(const MonitoringElements& current) = 0;
    virtual void risingEdge() = 0;
};

class MonitorManager final{
public:


    void addCondition(ICondition* condition){
        m_conditions.push_back(condition);
    }

    //constantly monitoring every x seconds
    void monitorOnce(){
        update();
        for(int i = 0; i < m_conditions.size(); ++i)
            if(m_conditions.at(i)->didTrigger(m_monitorElements)){
                m_conditions.at(i)->risingEdge();
            }
    }

private:
    void update(){
        //read sensor values here
        //update m_monitorElements;
    }

    MonitoringElements m_monitorElements;
    std::vector<ICondition*> m_conditions;
};
```